# NodeJS Google Storage unable to create new Bucket with gcloud utility

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, gcloud-node

So i am having some trouble with the gcloud plugin for Node.

I can create a bucket manually via their GUI and then use that container just fine to write files in my node program using the gcloud library provided by google.

The problem comes when i try to create a new bucket.

```
storage.createBucket('bucket1', function(err, bucket) {
                                      console.log(err)
                                      console.log(bucket)
                                    });
```

This always returns:

```
{ [Error: Invalid argument.]
  errors:
  [ { domain: 'global',
      reason: 'invalid',
      message: 'Invalid argument.' }],
   code: 400,
   message: 'Invalid argument.}
```

So i get that it thinks that i am passing an "invalid argument" having said that in this so helpful message 3 times ... yet the bucket name i am using is unique for my google storage.  It follows the naming conventions to the best of my knowledge.

Any insights are most welcome.

Here is the string i use for setting up the link:

```
 storage = gcloud.storage({
              keyFilename: __dirname + '/../credentials/XXXXXXXX-b1e05a5128e9.json',
              projectId: 'XXXXXXXX'
            });
```

Note that i am not having any trouble reading and writing to a bucket that i created manually via the GUI.  Just cannot create a new bucket.

I also tried with what should be a unique name globally across all of the cloud storage:

```
'com-missingmarble-bucket1'
```

**Edit**:
Giving the API test as per steven's suggestion yields the same response.  I authenticated the browser with oAuth ... a little different than the auth done in the node api but the result is the same.  while it is possible that i did not format my request in the API tester correctly here is what i get:

Request:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=XXXXXXXXX&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer xxxxxxxxxx
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
 "name": "com-missingmarble-bucket1"
}
```

Response:

```
    400 Bad Request

    {
     "error": {
      "errors": [
       {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid",
        "message": "Invalid argument."
       }
      ],
      "code": 400,
      "message": "Invalid argument."
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the code where you're initializing the gcloud storage connection as well as what version of gcloud you're using? The code you're using should work (though "bucket1" is taken -- names are shared across all Storage accounts). If you were using a name that was taken, you would receive an error with a message saying so. This is an error somewhere else.

Comment: Stephen thanks for getting back .. still stuck ... see edits above for more details.  Though i did not know about the global restriction on bucket names that unfortunately does not seem to be the issue. ... ps ... gcloud@0.11.0

Comment: I just can't figure this one out. The fact that you're able to download and upload with the same connection makes it difficult to see where the createBucket attempt could be going wrong. The 400 error code comes straight from the API: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes. Would you mind trying the API explorer to make the same request? https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/insert#try-it

Just to elaborate on the API explorer, that's the same API call we make: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-node/blob/v0.11.0/lib/storage/index.js#L202

Comment: Well based on your comments that it is the exact same interface i would have to expect that the API explorer would respond the same.  Which it did ... so at least 1+1 still = 2 which i guess is a win. So now i am left with the feeling that i am on the bleeding edge again.  ... adding comments above with the results of the api test

Comment: Just to be sure i just went back to the GUI for google cloud storage and created a new bucket manually without any trouble.

Comment: Are you using a brand new Google Developer Console project, reusing an existing one?

Comment: Could it be that your project, XXXXXXX, is not valid? Make sure project exactly matches our project ID number.

Comment: This is an existing project and the same project id works just fine for uploading/downloading images.  Just having this problem when trying to create a new directory.  Still no joy.

Comment: So i read Brandon's comment again and he said Account Number.  I had the account name in there and as all was working for upload/download i did not second guess that.  Substituted the account number and am now able to create directories.  Thanks so much for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment above, it sounds like your issue is resolved...

For future people looking at this question, it sounds like the issue was you need to provide which *project* the bucket should belong to while creating it.

When you upload/download a file you specify a bucket, so Google doesn't need to know the project ID / number because the bucket is globally unique and tied to a single project.

On the flip side, when you're creating a bucket, it's possible that a single set of credentials has access to multiple projects, so you need to specify which project the bucket should belong to.